# jQuery html() function not working on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with jQuery on mobile browsers. Problem is when AJAX  script returns result, jQuery fails to html() (or innerHTML) div element. When I test it on desktop browser, jQuery didn't fail to html() selected div. Can someone explain me why mobile browsers fails to  perform  html(). I am using DatePicker that calls html() function when date is changed. Here is code that I am using

jsFiddle: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/6hm3F/)

***EDIT 1:***

Problem with input type"text" was resolved. Put I have problem with select option tag. When I am on mobile browser, html function fails to inner html.

Here is updated jsFiddle: [Edited jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6hm3F/1/)

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" placeholder="Pick date">
<input type="text" name="sometext" id="sometext" value="SomeText">
<select id="opt" name="opt"><option value=1>1</option><option value=2>2</option></select>
```

JS code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {      
$("#datepicker").datepicker({

                dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                minDate: 0,
                onSelect: function (date, instance) {
                    alert (date);
                     var newoption= "<select><option value=new1>New value 1</option><option value=new2>New value2</option></select>";
              $("#opt").html(newoption);
                    /*
                    I will disable ajax in this example because result is correc
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "nesto.php",
                        data: "date=" + date,
                        success: function (result) {
                            window.optionValue=result;
                            alert (result);



                        }
                    });
                    */

                }
            }); 
           });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `sometext` is a input you need to use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

> The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea.

*Code*

```
$("#sometext").val(date);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Xju/)

### EDIT

You need to only create *options* not *select*.

Use

```
var newoption= "<option value=new1>New value 1</option><option value=new2>New value2</option>";
$("#opt").html(newoption);
```

instead of

```
var newoption= "<select><option value=new1>New value 1</option><option value=new2>New value2</option></select>";
$("#opt").html(newoption);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7K9M7/)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have a problem with select option tag. I edited my post. Can you please tell me why select option tag is not working?